# Hybris type system update in cluster

Tags: types, system, sap-commerce-cloud

We are planning to do a Zero Downtime deployment. SAP recommends that we run Hybris update in one of the nodes in the cluster with a new type system name while other nodes can continue to be with the earlier type system.

I am not able to think of a case where not using a different name would break the system. I understand that a new type system will make sure the models are generated newly while the other non-updated nodes can be on the old models. But what happens if I dont give a different name? Is there a scenario where it would break? I can't think of any.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it could break if you use the same name.  The point about a different type system name is that it can then have two parallel type systems / type metadata.  The nodes on the original release remain on the original type system & see the older metadata.  The updated node(s) see the new type system with added columns / tables.  If you use the same name, both refer to the same type system & the original nodes may break as they don't have the code that matches the updated type metadata.

The aim here (after creating the new type system) is either a rolling update (restart individual nodes one-at-a-time with the new type system name) or a blue-green deployment (new set of nodes in a second cluster using the new type system name, initially not publicly visible but then blue/green clusters are swapped).

Either way you have a period of time running both old and new nodes in parallel & both need their own notion of the type system that correlates with the code release they have deployed.

Note: there are also code/developer-level considerations when doing this.  You generally need to code to handle new fields/types being null/empty - as the old nodes will still be creating some level of data during the parallel run period & the old nodes will not populate new items in the updated type schema.  Therefore new code needs to be able to cope with the missing/null entries.

Comment: Thanks Neil. I understand why it is used. But I am not able think of a case where it could break. Can you give me an example DB schema change where the change done through items.xml (adding a new ENUM, changing index etc) could break if we dont use Type System Versioning?

Comment: It is not about the type system itself breaking.  It is about code that does not understand the type system version.  But you can do what you like ...